# MVC 5 How to submit an ajax search in a form

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, post, model-view-controller, get

I am trying to add a search function to a form. It is a multiselect list box filled with categories, that when selected will cause the table at the bottom to filter accordingly. As a result I have two forms the one at the top is an ajax search request. I have a hiddenfor in the other form, for the categories selected when they actually need to post. The problem is when I click search, both forms post, it doesn't seem to register the fact the form is outside of the other form. I cannot figure out how to have the first form be a get request, I thought I configured it in the options, but apparently I'm missing something.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "get",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "vendorList"
    }))
{
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.catIds, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.catIds, new MultiSelectList(Model.Categories, "Value", "Text", Model.catIds), new { @class = "chzn-select", data_placeholder = "Select  Categories..." })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.catIds)
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />

        </div>
    </div>
}
```

This is the other form...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "item", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.catIds)

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken();

...attribute setting

                <div class="form-group col-sm-12" id="vendorList">
                    <div class="post-title" style="margin-top: 0em">
                        <h3 style="left:auto">Invite Vendors</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" id="checkall">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Select All
                                        </button>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><b>VENDOR #</b></td>
                                    <td><b>VENDOR</b></td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="checkboxes">

                                @foreach (var item in Model.AllVendorUsers)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="checkbox" name="InvitedVendors" value=@item.Id>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @item.CompanyName
                                        </td>

                                        <td>
                                            @item.User.PhoneNumber
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <button type="submit" id="btn_Create" class="btn pull-right" value="Create">Finish</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: Show you whole view.

Comment: What parts do you need? I posted the other form, only thing I left out were the attributes. An addendum is that when I do not use ajax, the form works as anticipated. I know I am supposed to put the part that is recycled in a partial view, but for now I just need to get this working, then I'll add it.

Comment: Can't see anything to indicate that both forms would post back at the same time. Put a break point in both methods to be sure that's what is actually happening. `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.catIds)` in the second form does not make sense since its value is going to be the initial value when the page first loads (unless you have some javascript that updates it based on the selections in the first form)

Comment: They are two separate forms, when I remove the ajax call, and use form(method="get") it works fine, but when I try the ajax it runs both of the them, and posts the form, instead of reusing the get method to filter the table. Using breakpoints just tells me that the form is posting. Though it throws a anti-forgery token is not found error.

Comment: On a hunch I did a check, the second form is NOT submitting. What is happening is the first form is posting, instead of running a get. I filled out values for the second form, and they did not show up when I used breakpoints in the controller. Though I clearly state in the ajax form that the method is a get, it is somehow being overridden and is posting.

Comment: Are you sure you have included `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, based on Stephen's suggestion of checking the package (it was there), I uninstalled it, then installed a fresh copy from nuget. Now it works perfectly, I have no idea why it wouldn't work before (out of date, or corrupt?). Thank you for your help Stephen.